Does the set of evolution operators in QM form any known algebraic structure (e.g., a monoid)?
The evolution operator, $U(t,t_0)$, in quantum mechanics is defined by
$$
|\Psi(t)\rangle = U(t,t_0)|\Psi(t_0)\rangle.
$$
with $t\geq t_0$. Is the set of such evolution operators, specified by two time arguments, closed under operator multiplication? Let me elaborate a bit.
If $U(t_1,t_0)$ evolves the state from $t_0$ to $t_1(\geq t_0)$, and $U(t_2,t_1)$ evolves the state from $t_1$ to $t_2(\geq t_1)$, then from the defining equation it readily follows that
$$
U(t_2,t_0)=U(t_2,t_1)U(t_1,t_0), \quad t_2\geq t_1\geq t_0
$$
i.e., the product is also an evolution operator that takes the state from $t_0$ to $t_2(\geq t_0)$. Note that, in defining the evolution operator, I have assumed that its first argument is greater than or equal to its second argument. Moreover, the product of two $U$'s is defined in a way that the second argument of the first $U$ must match the first argument of the second $U$. Can such a set said to be closed w.r.t multiplication?
Does in any sense the time-evolution operators form a meaningful algebraic structure such as a monoid? I am not sure about the closure.

They form a strongly continous semi-group or $C_0$-Semi-group

I am not sure whether the closure is satisfied. Can you help me with that?

The wanted structure is called groupoid.
